# I can't first login to mysql via brew

Tags: mysql, macos, apple-m1

hello i'm using macbook pro with m1 chip.

I tried to install mysql via homebrew supported by mac osx like below.
`$ brew install mysql`
`$ brew services start mysql` or `$ mysql.server start`
`$ mysql -u root`

it looked like okay. but i can't log in it. this is the error i encountered

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

so I googled and they gave some solutions 
they said

1. I should log in without password first with `--skip-grant-tables`
2. and then set the root password like `alter user root identified by 'root'`

`$ mysql.server start --skip-grant-tables`
`$ mysql -u root`
`$ alter user root identified by 'root'`

and then I got this error like below.

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

According to above message, I should log in without --skip-grant-tables option and try to change password, but you know I can't.

is there someone who know this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is that `root` shouldn't be used unless you're setting up the database for the very first time for fixing something that is really, really broken. Restart MySQL without trying to circumvent the authentication safeties and connect with the help of `sudo`:

```
sudo mysql
```

This will connect you to the database engine. From there you will need to create an account that can be used as an admin:

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Now, whenever you need to connect to MySQL, you can use the `admin` account, which has full permissions.

Comment: Thanks so much for your sincerely reply.
I tried your steps, I got this error in mysql
`mysql> create user 'admin'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'admin1';`

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement`

Comment: In --skip-grant-tables mode, I think I can't change some variables in mysql...

Comment: As suggested in the answer, you'll need to restart MySQL in normal mode. The `--skip-grant-tables` mode is not something you want to use unless something is very, very broken.

Comment: but I can't log in mysql first just after installation. Once I typed `sudo mysql`, I received 'ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
so I asked this question.

Comment: Have you run `mysql_secure_installation` since installing MySQL?

Comment: I think that I tried, but it asked to me user root password and I thouht I didn't set any password. so I couldn't pass to next steps.

Is there first password or something?